# ReactJS image not loading

Tags: reactjs

I want to show images into a grid. The grid is appearing on the screen but the images are not loading

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Grid (props) {

    console.log(props.arrOfObj);

  const cells = props.arrOfObj.map(obj => 
    <div style={{ backgroundColor: "#555555"}} 
    className="item">{
            <img src={obj.image} alt={obj.image} width={250} height={250} /> 
    }</div>)

  return (

    <div className="container">
      {cells}
    </div>
  )
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you images loading from a server or are they loading from your `static` folder? 
The image paths are relative so this means they must be available under your `static` folder

Comment: they are in a folder. the path shown in alt is same as the image

Comment: To be accessible in the browser, you need to have the images in the `public` folder, you get more information on the react [docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/) website

Comment: your code here looks fine, may be you need to recheck on paths